# How can I implement MQTT on an STM32F030K6T6?

Tags: mqtt, microcontrollers, stm32, arm

The controller in question is an [STM32F030K6T6](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/microcontrollers/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus/stm32f0-series/stm32f0x0-value-line/stm32f030k6.html), which has an ARM® 32-bit Cortex® -M0 low power core, 32 kB Flash memory and 4 kB SRAM. It interfaces an SIM808 for Internet connectivity.

The resources are quite limited regarding the memory.

- Is it possible to implement MQTT on this device?
- What requirements should a microcontroller match to be able to use/run MQTT?

(I am not asking about a complete protocol stack implementation.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it possible to implement MQTT on this device?

Any device that has **TCP/IP layer** can implement MQTT.

> What requirements should a microcontroller match to be able to use/run MQTT?

You need to ask the following questions to know whether your device runs MQTT.

- Is my device having TCP/IP or networking support?
- Is there some memory and disk space available on device?
- Is a ready made MQTT client that can used on the device platform?
- Is there a network connectivity to the server?

Ref: [MQTT Support](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/can_my_device_run_mqtt10?lang=en)

Comment: Then the question boils down to: can you make do with 32 kB code memory.

Comment: @Ghanima, I could say no, but I'm trying to give an overview as what hardware is needed to run MQTT.

Comment: There is a MQTT library for Arduino : https://github.com/256dpi/arduino-mqtt which is low on memory

Comment: What's the minimum mem size does it need?

Comment: The Eclipse Paho project has an embedded C client that is very lightweight but also quite flexible: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.embedded-c. Might be worth a look.

Comment: The "disk space" requirement here is fundamentally mistaken, especially for the *client* end of the conversation which is what the question asks about.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, you are correct

Answer (score 11):

The mbed [mmqt library](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/mqtt/wiki/Using-MQTT) doesn't seem to document any memory requirements as likely to be limiting, and can reasonably be assumed to be targetted at this sort of small-footprint device as an endpoint. You could fairly trivially import the library into a similar device platform using the online compiler and check the code footprint at least.